# Question about the solution to the heat equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

The question I am attempting to solve is to show that the solution to the heat equation of a rod of length $10$ with initial temperature distribution given by $u(x,0)=f(x)$ is $$\frac{a_0}{2} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\text{exp}\left(-\left(\frac{\alpha n \pi}{10}\right)^2 t\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{10} \right ) $$

Yet after my working I get the answer to be $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\text{exp}\left(-\left(\frac{\alpha n \pi}{10}\right)^2 t\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{10} \right )$$ which looks to be correct according to the solution to the heat equation I looked at online.

I'm wondering though if this is actually correct and if it is how do I show that it is actually equal to $$\frac{a_0}{2} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\text{exp}\left(-\left(\frac{\alpha n \pi}{10}\right)^2 t\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{10} \right ) $$Thanks.

Comment: it depends on the boundary condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$. Without knowing what kind of function $f(x)$ is, it is impossible to answer to your question : is the Fourier series of $f(x)$ made of $\sin$ or $\cos$ functions or both ?

Comment: Here is all the question gives. It won't let me upload it directly to the site sorry. http://imgur.com/321cJsI

Comment: It doesn't say what kind of function $f(x)$ is though?

Comment: According to the wording of the problem, your solution is incomplete. You should obtain : $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \text{exp}\left(-\left(\frac{\alpha n \pi}{10}\right)^2 t\right) \left(a_n\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{10} \right )+b_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{10} \right ) \right)$$ . Then, you have to find what are the coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ in order to agree with what is specified in the wording. Obviously $b_n=0$. To find $a_n$ , expand $f(x)$ in Fourier series : express $a_n$ on the form of some integrals of $f(x)$.

Comment: In my solution I assumed $u(0,t)=0$ and $u(10,t)=0$ would that be where the error is then? I thought that was what it meant when it said that the ends are insulated? Because if that is right then my solution follows?

Comment: Why do you assumed that ?. It is not specified in the wording of the problem. And your assumption is false if $f(0)\neq 0$ and/or if $f(10)\neq 0$.

Comment: I thought that is what is meant when it says the ends are insulated. Obviously I was wrong. I don't know how to solve the problem then? Is there any derivations I could use or could I trouble you to give me a rough step by step to arrive at the solution?

Comment: It's no longer a math problem, but a question of physics. As far as I know, insulated boundary doesn't mean that the temperature is null or constant along the bondary. The gradiant of temperature is nul because the flux is nul from the medium to the boundary. This is why $b_n=0$.